# PHP and timezone

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I am using `strtotime()` to get a timestamp from a date and time string. I will be running `strtotime()` during the summer (daylight savings) to give me a timestamp of a winter date (non-daylight savings).

In the winter, I will need to convert my timestamp to a readable date using `date()` -- will it be the same date/time I put into `strtotime()` during the summer?

On each one of my pages, I am setting my timezone by `date_default_timezone_set` with my city.

So, running this during the summer (daylight savings):

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
echo strtotime("Dec 1 2014 8:00 am");
```

Gives me a certain timestamp 1417449600.

Will running this during the winter (non-daylight savings) return 8:00am as I need it to do?

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
echo date("g:ia",1417449600);
```

Comment: https://eval.in/190000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If the timezone you set is doesn't explicitly say whether it's standard or daylight-savings time, it automatically determines the state of DST from the time that you give it and the rules for when the timezone switches into and out of DST.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. A UNIX timestamp such as 1417449600 represents a completely, globally, universally unique point in time, independent of fussy timezone notation. There's only *one* *"December 1st 2014 8 am in Los Angeles"*, which is the same point in time as *"December 1st 2014 17:00 CET"* and a number of other local notations across the world. The UNIX timestamp 1417449600 expresses that *point in time*, regardless of whatever your wall clock says exactly.

When you format this unique point in time back to a more human readable format using `date()`, it figures out what exactly the time must be formatted at based on the set timezone. It won't change based on what the time or DST settings are *now*.